# Go gRPC []bytes encoding/decoding

Tags: arrays, go, google-api, byte, grpc

I'm developing a set of functions (based on KNative Serving + Eventing) and I'm having a lot of problems getting the decoded data on the receiving-end if the stream.

So, I'm implementing a couple of functions that, will use the Google APIs (via `google.golang.org/api/slides/v1`) to grab a Google Slides Presentation (a `struct` from the library), encode it as a `[]byte` and send it over the network with protobuf/gRPC.
This appears to be working correctly, however, when I try to decode it back into a `Presentation` I'm getting an error. Printing out the `Decode` call returns only `EOF`.

Here's the proto definition:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package api;

message ParserRequest { 
  bytes Presentation = 1;
}

message ParserResponse {
  int32 Status = 1;
  bytes Document = 2;
}

service ParserService {
// ParsePresentation parse the Google Slides presentation it into the SDR representation
  rpc ParsePresentation(ParserRequest) returns (ParserResponse) {}
}
```

The sending function is similar to:

```
presentation, err := svc.Presentations.Get(docID).Do()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve data from document: %+v", err)
}

if presentation != nil {
    log.Printf("Calling Parser...")

    address := "PORT:IP"
    conn, err := grpc.DialContext(ctx, address, grpc.WithInsecure())
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Dial Error! %+v", err)
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("could not connect shipping service: %+v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    log.Printf("Marshalling data...")
    // data, err := presentation.MarshalJSON()
    // data, err := json.Marshal(presentation)

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(&buf)
    err = enc.Encode(&presentation)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Encode Error: %+v", err)
        log.Fatal("encode error:", err)
    }
    data := buf.Bytes()
    log.Println(data) //[255 211 255 129 3 1 1 12 ...]

    cli, err := parser.NewParserServiceClient(conn).ParsePresentation(ctx, &parser.ParserRequest{Presentation: data})
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Cli call Error! %+v", err)
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to get parser service: %+v", err)
    }
    log.Printf("Result: %d", cli.Status)
}
```

On the other end, I should now decode the `data` array and "translate" back into a `Presentation` struct, doing so via:

```
func (c *parserService) ParsePresentation(ctx context.Context, in *pb.ParserRequest) (*pb.ParserResponse, error) {
    log.Printf("ParserService.ParsePresentation was called!")

    if in.Presentation == nil {
        log.Fatalf("Missing parameter Google Slides document.")
    }

    sdrDocument, err := gslides_parser.ParsePresentationBytes(in.Presentation)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to parse the Google Slides presentation: %+v", err)
    }

    presentation, err := json.Marshal(sdrDocument)
    return &pb.ParserResponse{Status: 200, Document: presentation}, nil
}
```

Than, when it gets to the `gslides_parser.ParsePresentationBytes(in.Presentation)` will then be decoded:

```
func ParsePresentationBytes(presentationParam []byte) (sdr.Document, error) {

    var (
        document     sdr.Document
        presentation slides.Presentation
    )

    log.Printf("PresentationBytes gob decoder")
    log.Println(presentationParam) // Output: [255 211 255 129 3 1 1 12 ...]
    // err := json.Unmarshal(presentationParam, &presentation)

    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(presentationParam)
    log.Printf("New decoder...")
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(buf)
    log.Printf("Decode...")
    log.Println(&presentation) // Output: &{[]  [] <nil> <nil>   []  {0 map[]} [] []}
    err := dec.Decode(&presentation)
    log.Printf("Done decoding...")

    if err != nil {
        // Never gets here
        document = sdr.Document{}
        (...)
    } else {
        log.Printf("PresentationBytes Error!")
    }

    return document, nil
}
```

So, why can't I decode the information? I don't see anything terribly wrong with this code, but I'm also a golang newb so I may have some error that is eluding me.
Isn't gob the appropriate way of dealing with this? I tried simply marshalling/unmarshalling but that also produces errors.

Comment: Remove grpc / protobuf from the problem to start. Try this:  get your presentation doc, gob encode, save to disk.  In another, separate program, read the file from disk, gob decode and see if you have your original data.

Comment: Also be wary of sending a large payload in a single gRPC message. Using a `[]byte` to send files is tempting - but if the payload is greater than 4MB you're going to hit client-side limitations. So streaming file-chunks would be the next step in that situation...

Comment: @colminator yes, I'm aware of the limitations but for this case it's enough, though, good thinking on the chunk-streaming.. Might as well just setup the application to handle that..

Comment: @sberry That's an option yes, thanks.